# New \rightarrowtail symbol

Tags: arrows

I want to redefine `\rightarrowtail` so that its arrowheads look like those from `\leftrightarrow`. I have already redefined `\twoheadrightarrow`, since it also looks different from `\leftrightarrow`, using the following code:

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{%
            {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}
        }
\makeatother
    \newcommand{\newtwoheadrightarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\mkern2.5mu\rightarrow}{\rightarrow\mkern2.5mu}}}}
\renewcommand{\twoheadrightarrow}{\newtwoheadrightarrow}
```

However, I don't know how to do something analogous to redefine `\rightarrowtail`, since I could not find only an arrowhead symbol to `\superimpose` over `\rightarrow`.

Comment: You might be interested in [tikzpfeile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpfeile)

Comment: There is no arrow like the one I am looking for in thid package.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but a good approximation with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645771/101651
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\onlytip}{\tikz{\draw[->](0,0)--(.001,0);}}

\newcommand{\newrightarrowtail}{\mathrel{\raisebox{-.165pt}{\onlytip}\mkern-6.5mu\rightarrow}}
\renewcommand{\rightarrowtail}{\newrightarrowtail}

\begin{document}
\[a \rightarrowtail b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply use `>->` arrow type?

Comment: Thus it becomes a one liner: `\renewcommand{\rightarrowtail}{\tikz\draw[>->] (0,0) -- (10pt,0);}`

Comment: @antshar Because the TikZ tip is less defined than the `\rightarrowtail`. Enlarge the picture and you'll see