# Only the arrow tip

Tags: arrows

I'd like to have only the tip of this arrow: $\to$.
I.e. I'd like take the part after `|`-symbol of this

```
|\mathrel{\mkern-17mu}\rightarrow
```

I accept also a latex-code that makes white the part before `|` of the code I just posted.
Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two possibilities, depending on whether you want any of the stem of the arrow.

[image]

The first option uses `trimclip` to cut off most of the stem. The second uses `TikZ` to draw an arrow with (almost) no stem. Note that you must load the `arrows.meta` library to get the arrow the same size and shape as `\to`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\totip}{\mathrel{\clipbox*{{.685\width} {-.5ex} {\width} {1.5ex}}{$\to$}}}

\newcommand{\tootip}{\mathrel{\tikz[anchor=base]{\draw[->](0,0)--(.01,0);}}}

\begin{document}

$a\totip b \to c$

$a\tootip b \to c$

\end{document}
```